# Can't search products in magento 2

Tags: search, magento2

When i try to search a product it [show nothing](http://prntscr.com/l2rqn8). And i check the exception, it show some bug

> [2018-10-06 01:42:56] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list, query was: SELECT `search_synonyms`.* FROM `search_synonyms` WHERE (MATCH (synonyms) AGAINST ('greene tweed n038406502sd653 o ring 2560 id x 0151 cx in' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) [] []
>   [2018-10-06 01:42:56] main.CRITICAL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1191 Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list, query was: SELECT `search_synonyms`.* FROM `search_synonyms` WHERE (MATCH (synonyms) AGAINST ('greene tweed n038406502sd653 o ring 2560 id x 0151 cx in' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) [] []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE search_synonyms ADD FULLTEXT (synonyms);
```

Try this to add a full text index.

Comment: Thanks for your help.